# android image gallery-swapping is not working

Tags: android, image, gallery, image-gallery, android-gallery

I am new to android. I am using Intent to show full screen image and swipe between the images. The code is like:

(I am using grid to display images, Once I click on Image in grid I am calling intent)

```
Gridview_sponsor = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewSponsor);

Gridview_sponsor
                    .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                            AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption(imagesName.get(pos)
                                    .toString());
                            diaBox.show();

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
            Gridview_sponsor.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(
                            Uri.parse("file://" + imagesName.get(position)),
                            "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

Previously it  was working properly. But after uninstalling existing app it stop swapping.

In above code `imagesName.get(position)` contains the image path which I am assigning to `ACTION_VIEW` intent. But it is only showing the image in full screen and zoom in ,zoom out functionality is working fine.But the images are not getting swipe from that folder

Comment: very limited info, elaborate more

Comment: I am using grid view for displaying images. once I click on Image I am showing big image. Thanks for your interest

Comment: @akkilis:I have edited my question in that i have elaborated scenario .Please help me

Comment: I have the same problem on my rooted device.In which i had uninstall default galley application and after installing some other .apk's i have install the gallery application again in `/system/app` folder.But after re installing it,swapping functionality of gallery is not working.